# How to grab a block of text from file with Batch

Tags: parsing, text, batch-file

Im attempting to get a block of text from a file I have already created and store that information into a new file.  The text file id like to parse is set up like this:

HostName:                             xxxxxx

(8 or so lines of information)

HostName:                             xxxxxx

The largest problem I am having is that between the blocks of text I am specifically looking for the word "admin".  I am able to find and return the line with the word admin in it, now I need to write a loop to grab the information above and below if the word admin is found within that block of text (I was going to use an empty line as the delimiter as thats consistent throughout my file).

Ive written a few for loops but none of them have given me what id like.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to know which programming language you are currently leveraging and some sample code.

Comment: "Batch" isn't a language. What language are you trying to use, and what operating system? [We're not mind readers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/172661) - we only have the information you provide in your question. Also, it's helpful if you post what you've tried so far that isn't working.

Comment: Im writing my program in MSDOS Batch (Im not sure how else to explain it). At the moment the code I have is 
    
echo SCHTASKS: >> results.txt
    schtasks /query /fo list /v > schtasks.txt
    findstr  /i "administrator*" schtasks.txt >> results.txt
    echo. >> results.txt

That code will execute the commands that I need to create my file, but now I am not sure how I can take the information out of that file as I stated above.  Thanks again.

Comment: Are you using MSDOS or Windows? It seems that you are referring to shell scripts either using command.com or cmd.exe as command line interpreter.

Comment: I am using windows.  Again I apologize cause I clearly dont get the concept of shell scripts, but my script is being run through a .bat file so cmd.exe.
I was going to use powershell however the computer that my program must be run on is outdated and does not have powershell 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program below do what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Create the info removing empty lines
(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('schtasks /query /fo list /v') do echo %%a) > schtasks.txt
rem Add an additional "HostName:" line at end as delimiter
echo HostName: >> schtasks.txt
rem Create a vector of number of lines containing "HostName:"
set i=0
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "HostName:" schtasks.txt') do (
   set /A i+=1
   set header[!i!]=%%a
)
rem Seek for the LINES containing "admin"
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /I "administrator" schtasks.txt') do (
   rem Seek for the NEXT section that contains "admin" line
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do if %%a gtr !header[%%i]! set thisSection=%%i
   rem Locate that section
   set /A start=header[!thisSection!], nextSection=thisSection+1
   set /A end=header[!nextSection!]-1
   rem ... and show it
   set line=0
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (schtasks.txt) do (
      set /A line+=1
      if !line! geq !start! if !line! leq !end! echo %%a
   )
   echo ----------------------------------------------
)
del schtasks.txt
```

PS - Of course that MS-DOS/Windows Batch is a programming language!

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Thank you for taking the time to write this for me.  Also, thank you for the comments as this code is very easy to trace and learn from.

Comment: One more question if you dont mind.  I've tried to edit the code a bit with no luck cause at the moment it will overwrite any previous instances of the word administrator (I mean it overwrites %%a so only the very last instance of the word will be displayed). Its probably a simple fix however ive spent quite a bit of time again on this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. The Batch file was developed for just one instance of "admin" word in accordance with your specifications. Although the modification is not very hard, it is not so simple either; I need some time to do it... Hint: the `for ... do set admin=%%a` command must enclose all the lines below it, starting with `set admin=%%a`

Comment: Thank you very much Aacini.  Ive spent a fair amount of time writing a nested loop that uses a temp variable to check against the value of %%a and then either passes that value to the rest of the code, or continues to search.  Sadly it does not work (I can successfully pull out the line numbers where "administrator" is located, however printing to my file usually results in the first instance of administrator, then everything inside of schtasks that comes after that.)

Comment: I completed the requested modification, it is in the same code above. In all programming languages, but particularly in Batch, an apparently _simple_ modification may lead to large changes in the program. Take this into account the next time you want to post a  question here or in any other site: State _complete_ requirements from the very beginning!

Comment: Thank you once again Aacini.  I went into this expecting to learn more about writing scripts, however another (and possibly more valuable) lesson learned is to understand the requirements of a program BEFORE I start coding.